# Removing first element completely from a given XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to remove the first element completely using powershell but running into an issue. Looking for any pointers.

`$SeedTemp_XML.InnerXml` is the `system.xml.xmlnode` below:

```
<Seed DcFolder="WAN">

<Wiring Action="Add">
<Start DeviceType="" DeviceRegex="" Scope="" ItfNames="" />
<End DeviceType="" DeviceRegex="" Scope="" ItfNames="" />
<DevicePattern Scope="Local" />
</Wiring>

<Wiring Action="Add">
<Start DeviceType="Server" DeviceRegex="DeviceA" Scope="Datacenter" ItfNames="" />
<End DeviceType="Server" DeviceRegex="DeviceB" Scope="Datacenter" ItfNames="" />
<DevicePattern Scope="Local" />
</Wiring>
</Seed>
```

when I try `$SeedTemp_XML.Seed.FirstChild.RemoveAll()`
it ends up like the below which is expected but need to remove the empty `<Wiring></Wiring>` too..

```
<Seed DcFolder="WAN">

<Wiring>
</Wiring>

<Wiring Action="Add">
<Start DeviceType="Server" DeviceRegex="DeviceA" Scope="Datacenter" ItfNames="" />
<End DeviceType="Server" DeviceRegex="DeviceB" Scope="Datacenter" ItfNames="" />
<DevicePattern Scope="Local" />
</Wiring>
</Seed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing all children of the first child of `Seed`.

To remove the first child of `Seed` you need to do this:

`$SeedTemp_XML.Seed.RemoveChild($SeedTemp_XML.Seed.FirstChild)`